# Resampling signal to get N amount of points from signal

Tags: signal-processing, octave, resampling

I have a signal and I would like to get **n** equally spaced points from it.

I was thinking of using `resample` as a way to do this but I wasn't sure of the correct values to use.

**Example:** I have a sine wave signal sampled at 8000 Hz but I want to get just 4 equally spaced points from the signal.

```
fs=8000
len_of_sig=1.0; %length of signal in seconds
t=linspace(0,len_of_sig,fs*len_of_sig);
y=1*sin(1*(2*pi)*t);

spaced_points=resample(y,)
```

I'm not sure how to calculate the correct values to use to get just **n** equally spaced points **(like 4,5,6...points)**.

Any ideas?  I don't really need to use `resample`, I just thought that would be the quickest.

I'm using Octave 4.2.2 on Ubuntu 64bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the `resample` function doesn't need anything aside from the resampling factor itself:

> `y = resample (x, p, q, h)`
>
> Change the sample rate of x by a factor of p/q. This is performed using a polyphase algorithm. The impulse response h of the antialiasing filter is either specified or either designed with a Kaiser-windowed sinecard.

Suppose you have the variable `ndesired_samples`, which specifies how many samples you want in the end. Let `nsamp = fs*len_of_sig`.

The resampling factor is given by `ndesired_samples/nsamp`, hence `p` is the number of desired samples, and `q` is the number of total samples. Note that [resample divides `p` and `q` by their GCD internally](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/9511643/).

Beware of issues stemming from the polyphase structure and the Kaiser interpolation window. IIRC these are especially bad if `p` and `q` end up large after GCD (i.e. resampling 10000 samples to 8000 samples is OK, resampling 10000 points to 8001 warrants further caution).